# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \ln (1 + x)}{x} \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, euler-sums

I was playing around with trying to prove the following alternating Euler sum:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^2} = -\frac{5}{8} \zeta (3).$$
Here $H_n$ is the [Harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

At least two different proofs for this result that I could find can be seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk?lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk/499716#499716). Embarking on an alternative proof I did the following. From the [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) for the Harmonic number of
$$H_n = \int_0^1 \frac{1 - x^n}{1 - x} \, dx$$
I rewrote the alternating Euler sum as
\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^2} &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1 - x} \left [\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2} - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n^2} \right ]\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{-\pi^2/12 - \operatorname{Li}_2 (-x)}{1 - x} \, dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1 - x) \ln (1 + x)}{x} \, dx,
\end{align}
where integration by parts has been used. I expect this last integral can be knocked over with relative easy but I have been going around in circles now for quite some time without any success.

> So my question is, how can this last integral be evaluated (a real method is preferred) that does not rely on the alternating Euler sum I started out with?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Similarly to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3062262/515527) post. We have:
$$4ab=(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2$$
Thus we can take $a=\ln(1-x)$ and $b=\ln(1+x)$ to get:
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}dx=\frac14 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-x^2)}{x}dx-\frac14 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}dx$$
By setting $x^2 =t$ in the first integral and $\frac{1-x}{1+x}=t$ in the second one we get:
$$I=\frac18 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-t)}{t}dt -\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t^2}dt=\frac18 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2t}{1-t}dt-\frac12 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t^2}dt$$
$$=\frac18\sum_{n\ge 0}\int_0^1 t^n \ln^2 tdt-\frac12 \sum_{n\ge 0}\int_0^1 t^{2n}\ln^2 tdt$$
Using the following fact:
$$\int_0^1 t^a dt=\frac{1}{a+1}\Rightarrow \int_0^1 t^a \ln^k tdt=\frac{d^k}{da^k} \left(\frac{1}{a+1}\right)=\frac{(-1)^k k!}{(a+1)^{k+1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow I=\frac18\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{2}{(n+1)^3} -\frac12 \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{2}{(2n+1)^3}=\frac28 \zeta(3) -\frac78 \zeta(3)=-\frac58\zeta(3)$$

Comment: Now that's a nice trick! Thanks.

Comment: @omegadot I have edited my answer, it didn't update?

Comment: Yes. Now it has and thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

we can use the generating function :
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2}x^n=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$

which can be directly derived from  $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n}x^n=\frac12\ln^2(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(x)$

I can provide the proof if needed. and I think it was proved here on some post.