# Integral $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, alternative-proof

I am trying to solve by a different approach the fourth sum from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3301156/515527),  namely:
$$S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{nm(4n+m)} =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^4)}{x}dx= \frac{67}{32} \zeta(3) -\frac{\pi}{2}G$$

---

One way to solve it is similarly to my answer from there:
$$S=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx$$
From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3270072/515527) we know that:
$$\small \int_0^1 \frac{[m\ln(1+x)+n\ln(1-x)][q\ln(1+x)+p\ln(1-x)]}{x}dx=\left(\frac{mq}{4}-\frac{5}{8}(mp+nq)+2np\right)\zeta(3)$$
Thus by setting $m=0,n,p,q=1$ in the first integral we get that:
$$S=\frac{11}{8}\zeta(3)+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx=\frac{11}{8}\zeta(3)+I$$
$$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \int_0^1 x^{2n-1} \ln(1-x)dx=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_{2n}}{n^2}=\frac{23}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{2}G$$
And the result for $S$ follows. The last sum appears to be known, see $(659)$ from [here](http://www.pi314.net/eng/hypergse13.php), or alternatively since $I=2\Re\left( S(i)\right)$ just use the following identity:
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^2}H_n=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\ln(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln x \ln^2(1-x)+\zeta(3)$$
However I am trying to find a different method since the result is quite nice and I believe there's a nicer way to solve the integral without using such sums.

Thus I would appreciate to get some help with the following problem:

> Prove without using Euler's sum or polylogs that
>   $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx=\frac{23}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi}{2}G$$

I also tried to consider the following integral:
$$J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx$$
[$$\Rightarrow I+J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx\overset{x^2=t}=\frac12 \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-t)\ln(1+t)}{t}dt=-\frac{5}{16}\zeta(3)$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3085715/515527)

So now I am after the following integral:
$$I-J=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx=\frac74 \zeta(3)-\pi G$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt to compute $I-J$ using complex analysis method (I hope you don't mind.) Let $f(z) $ be an analytic function defined by $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{2\log(1+z)\log(1+iz)}z$ on the unit disk. By Cauchy's integral theorem, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,i]} f(z)dz - \int_{[0,1]} f(z) dz =&  \int_{[1,i]} f(z)dz.
\end{align*} Then the LHS is ($[0,i]$ is parametrized by $z = ix, x\in [0,1]$)
\begin{align*}
\int_{[0,i]} f(z)dz - \int_{[0,1]} f(z) dz =&\int_0^1 \frac{2\log(1+ix)\log(1-x)}{x} dx -\int_0^1 \frac{2\log(1+x)\log(1+ix)}x dx  \\
 =& \color{red}{\int_0^1 \frac{2\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\log(1+ix)}x dx}.
\end{align*} On the other hand, the RHS is ($[1,i]$ is parametrized by $z = e^{i\theta}, \theta \in [0,\frac\pi 2]$)
\begin{align*}
\int_{[1,i]} f(z)dz =&2i \int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \log(1+e^{i\theta})\log(1+ie^{i\theta}) d\theta \\
=&\color{blue}{2i\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\Big[\log\left(2\cos(\theta/2)\right) + i\theta/2\Big]\Big[\log(2\cos\left(\theta/2 +\pi /4\right)+i(\theta/2+\pi/4)\Big]d\theta }
\end{align*} where we have used $\log(1+e^{i\theta}) = \log(2\cos (\theta/2)) + i\theta/2$ for $|\theta|<\pi$.

Note that for all real $x$, it holds that $2\Re[\log(1+ix)] =  \ln(1+x^2)$. So by equating the real parts of $\color{red} {\text{red}}$ and $\color{blue} {\text{blue}}$ integrals, we get
\begin{align*}
I-J =& \Re\left[\int_0^1 \frac{2\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\log(1+ix)}x dx\right]\\
=&-\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}  \left(\theta+ \frac \pi 2\right)\log(2\cos (\theta/2)) -\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \theta \log(2\cos(\theta/2 + \pi /4)) d\theta\\
=& -\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}  \left(\theta+ \frac \pi 2\right)\log(2\cos (\theta/2)) -\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \left(\frac \pi 2 -\theta\right) \log(2\sin(\theta/2)) d\theta \\
=& \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \theta \log (\tan (\theta/2))d\theta -\frac \pi 2\left(\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \log(2\cos(\theta/2)) d\theta+\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \log(2\sin(\theta/2)) d\theta\right)\\
=& \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \theta \log (\tan (\theta/2))d\theta 
\end{align*} because
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \log(2\cos(\theta/2)) d\theta+\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \log(2\sin(\theta/2)) d\theta =& \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \log(2\cos(\theta/2)) d\theta+\int_{\frac \pi 2}^\pi \log(2\cos(\theta/2)) d\theta\\
=& \int_0^{\pi } \log(2\cos(\theta/2)) d\theta \\=& 0.
\end{align*}
Finally, using the Fourier series of $\displaystyle \log\left(\tan\left(\theta/2\right)\right) =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k-1}{k}\cos(k\theta)$, we get
\begin{align*}
I - J =&\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k-1}{k}\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\theta\cos(k\theta)d\theta\\
=&\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k-1}{k}\left(\frac{\pi\sin(k\pi /2)}{2k}+\frac{\cos(k\pi /2) - 1}{k^2}\right)\\
\overset{k=2j+1}=&\sum_{j=0}^\infty \left[\frac{\pi (-1)^{j+1}}{(2j+1)^2} +\frac 2{(2j+1)^3}\right]\\
=& -\pi \text{G} + \frac 7 4\zeta(3).
\end{align*}

Comment: To be fair I always have a hard time with complex analysis. Can you please explain me in more details the following: 
What is the point in applying Cauchy formula, when clearly:
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{2\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\log(1+ix)}x dx
=\int_0^1 \frac{2\log(1+it)\log(1-t)}{it} idt -\int_0^1 \frac{2\log(1+x)\log(1+ix)}x dx   =$$
This is by expanding the logarithm and  putting $x=t$ and multiplying by $\frac{i}{i}$ the first integral.

Comment: Also is this row:
$$2i\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\left[\ln\left(2\cos(\theta/2)\right) + i\theta/2\right]\left[\ln(2\cos\left(\theta/2 +\pi /4\right)+i(\theta/2+\pi/4)\right]d\theta
$$
A continuation of the RHS from there? (Seeing no equality sign confuses me a little). Then when we are equating the real parts of both sides, both sides means the equality from my first comment (after the parametrisation was done)?

Comment: Also you're sometimes using $\log$ and sometimes $\ln$. Is that meant to outline something?

Comment: I used $\ln$ for the real logarithm and $\log$ for the complex one, but I just edited my answer to use $\log$ exclusively. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There's nothing really special in the obvious calculation $$\int_0^1 \frac{2\log(1+it)\log(1-t)}{it} idt -\int_0^1 \frac{2\log(1+x)\log(1+ix)}x dx = \int_0^1 \frac{2\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\log(1+ix)}x dx$$ (it is edited now). But the point is that it contains the desired integral in its real part: $$\int_0^1 \frac{2\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\log(1+ix)}x dx =  \int_0^1 \frac{\log\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\left(\log(1+x^2) + 2i \arctan(x)\right)}x dx.$$

Comment: Thanks alot! I guessed that $\log$ is for the complex one, but then there was  $f(z) = \frac{2\log(1+z)\log(1+iz)}z$ instead of  $f(z) = \frac{2\ln(1+z)\log(1+iz)}z$ and it didn't add up. About your last comment, I guess by finding the imaginary part we get a closed from for following integral: $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\arctan x}{x}dx$$
Wait.. I guess I'm too tired now. From what side should I take that imaginary part?

Comment: I used $\log(1+z)$ because $z$ can also take non-real values $z=x+iy$ for $x^2+y^2 <(\le)1$. About your last comment, I guess you're right (though I found that the imaginary part of the RHS is not particularly easy to evaluate.) This may be related to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050696/proving-that-int-01-frac-arctan-xx-ln-left-frac1x21-x2-rightd), but I'm not sure. I hope it was helpful!

Comment: Indeed they might be since:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\arctan x}{x}dx\overset{(1-x)/(1+x)=t}=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t (\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan t)}{1-t^2}dt$$
$$=\frac{\pi^3}{16}-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t}dt-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1-t}dt$$
The first integral appears here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842284/evaluating-int-01-frac-arctan-x-log-x1xdx. But I don't think the second integral got an elementary closed form. Anyway I might look further into complex analysis so thanks for your time, it really helps me.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}I&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx\\
&=\Big[\ln x\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)\Big]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx
\end{align}
Let $R$ the function defined for $[0;1]$ by,
\begin{align}
R(x)&=\int_0^x \frac{2t\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{2tx^2\ln(tx)}{1+t^2x^2}\,dt
\end{align}For $0<A<1$,
\begin{align}\int_0^A \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\Big[R(x)\ln(1-x)\Big]_0^A+\int_0^A \frac{R(x)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=R(A)\ln(1-A)+\int_0^A \left(\int_0^1\frac{2tx^2\ln(tx)}{(1-x)(1+t^2x^2)}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&=R(A)\ln(1-A)+\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^A\frac{2tx^2\ln t}{(1-x)(1+t^2x^2)}\,dx\right)\,dt+\\
&\int_0^A \left(\int_0^1\frac{2tx^2\ln x}{(1-x)(1+t^2x^2)}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&=R(A)\ln(1-A)-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+A^2t^2)}{(1+t^2)t}\,dt-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t }{1+t^2}\,dt-\\
&2\ln(1-A)\int_0^1 \frac{t\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\int_0^A \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x)}\,dx \end{align}
Take the limit at $A=1$,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx&=-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t^2)}{(1+t^2)t}\,dt-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx\end{align}In the first integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx&=-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t\ln(1+t)}{(1+t)t}\,dt-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\\
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx
\end{align}In the second integral perform integration by parts,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\\
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{2x\ln^2 x}{1-x^2}\,dx+\frac{1}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\\
&2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx
\end{align}
In the second integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{3}{32}\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\\
&2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx+\frac{3}{16}\zeta(3)-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln t\arctan t}{1+t^2}\,dt+\\
&\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx
\\J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}\\
A&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^2 x}{1-x^2}\,dx
\end{align}In the latter integral perform the change of variable $y=x^2$:
\begin{align}A&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{7}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)
\end{align}On the other hand, perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$,
\begin{align}A&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) }{x}\,dx\\
B&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(1-x^2\right) }{x}\,dx
\end{align}In the latter integral perform the change of variable  $y=1-x^2$,\begin{align}B&=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
B&=\frac{1}{2}\zeta(3)\\
A+B&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(1-x\right) }{x}\,dx+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(1+x\right) }{x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2\left(1-x\right) }{x}\,dx+\Big[\ln x\ln(1+x)^2\Big]_0^1-2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx
\end{align}In the first integral perform the change of variable  $y=1-x$,\begin{align}A+B&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-2J\end{align}But,\begin{align}A+B&=\frac{9}{4}\zeta(3)\end{align}Therefore,\begin{align}J&=\boxed{-\dfrac{1}{8}\zeta(3)}\\
K&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
2K&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx-\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx+\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\text{G}\pi
\end{align}
Let $S$ the function defined on $[0;\infty]$ by,
\begin{align}
S(x)&=\int_0^x\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{x\ln(tx)}{1+t^2x^2}\,dt
\end{align}Observe that,
\begin{align}S(0)&=0,\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} S(x)=0\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\Big[S(x)\arctan x\Big]_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty \frac{S(x)}{1+x^2}\,dx\\
&=-\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)}{(1+x^2)(1+t^2x^2)}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&=-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{x\ln t}{(1+x^2)(1+t^2x^2)}dx\right)dt-\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln x}{(1+x^2)(1+t^2x^2)}dt\right)dx\\
&=A-\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx
\end{align}
Therefore,\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)\\
K&=\boxed{\frac{7}{16}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{4}\text{G}\pi}\\
\int_0^1 \frac{2x\ln x\ln(1-x)}{1+x^2}\,dx&=\frac{1}{2}\text{G}\pi-\frac{23}{32}\zeta(3)+\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln(1+x^2)}{1-x}\,dx\\
I&=\boxed{\frac{23}{32}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\text{G}\pi}
\end{align}
**NB:** I assume,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx=2\zeta(3)\end{align}
I have computed $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx$ using only univariate changes of variable and performing integration by parts.

PS: $\text{I}$ is linked to [Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^2}{ \sin x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714146/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-fracx2-sin-xdx) see:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2716753/186817

Comment: Thanks! It's not really obvious to me how how $I$ is related to that integral, but the closed form clearly is.

Comment: \begin{align}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^2}{ \sin x}dx&\overset{y=\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}=4\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan^2 x}{x}\,dx=-8\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\arctan x}{1+x^2}\,dx=-8K\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Applying the integration by parts and rearranging everything, we obtain

$$
J=\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1+x) \log \left(1+x^2\right)}{x} \textrm{d}x=-2\int_0^1\frac{x \log (x) \log (1+x)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x$$
$$+\int_0^1 \left(\frac{(1-x) \log (x) \log \left(1-x^2\right)}{1-x^2}-\frac{(1-x) \left(1+x^2\right) \log (x) \log \left(1-x^4\right)}{1-x^4}\right)\textrm{d}x.$$

The integrals $\displaystyle U=\int_0^1\frac{x \log (x) \log (1-x)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x$ and $\displaystyle V=\int_0^1\frac{x \log (x) \log (1+x)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x$ are easily calculated in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, (see pages $8$-$9$) by calculating $U-V$ and $U+V$. No need to use Euler sums or Polylogs, but you might need to accept Beta function.

Note that by expanding 
$$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{(1-x)\log (x) \log \left(1-x^2\right)}{1-x^2}-\frac{(1-x) \left(1+x^2\right) \log (x) \log \left(1-x^4\right)}{1-x^4}\right)\textrm{d}x$$
you only have Beta functions.

Similar approach for $I$.

That's all.

**ADDENDUM:** Since I mentioned the use of the integrals  $\displaystyle U=\int_0^1\frac{x \log (x) \log (1-x)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x$ and $\displaystyle V=\int_0^1\frac{x \log (x) \log (1+x)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x$, the sum $U+V$ reduces to the calculation of the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\log(x)\log(1-x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x$ evaluated separately in Section $2$, page $4$, in the new preprint  [A note presenting the generalization of a special logarithmic integral by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335149209_A_note_presenting_the_generalization_of_a_special_logarithmic_integral), with no use of Beta function, Polylogarithm, or Euler sums.

More generally (if you're possibly interested), we have 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log ^{2n-1}(x) \log(1-x)}{1+x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(2n)!\zeta (2n+1)-2\log(2)(1 -2^{-2n})(2n-1)!\zeta (2n)$$
$$-2^{-1-2n} (2n+1-2^{1+2n})(2n-1)!\zeta(2n+1)$$
$$-(2n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\zeta (2k)\zeta (2n-2k+1)+2^{-2n}(2n-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2^{2k}\zeta (2k)\zeta (2n-2k+1),$$
where $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function.

*This last result could be new in the literature.*

The case $U-V$ is easy to see it can be calculated again with no use of Beta function, Polylogarithm, or Euler sums.

Comment: I mentioned a few times that I don't have the book and I can't check anything there, but I think I can do $U$ and $V$ myself. Is there any particular reason on why you chose to go with $J$ instead of doing the same thing with $I$?

Comment: @Zacky maybe less useful for you, more useful for others.

Comment: @ user97357329: i have read the paper mentionned above. I'm glad to see some people read me ;) The method works fine for $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln^n\ln(1-x)}{1-x}dx$ but ok, the formula obtained is already well-known.

Comment: @FDP I'm sure people interested in double integrals may learn a lot from your posts that use heavily double integrals. I saw a post by Cornel from July 2014 (https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=658728870890581&set=a.222846247812181) that makes me think he has also been a big fan of symmetry for a long time ;) As regards the last integral you mentioned, even if it is known it is still interesting to have more ways to go for it.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, the integrals $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\textrm{d}x$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}\textrm{d}x$ may be seen as disguised forms of the integrals $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x$ and $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x\operatorname{Li}_2(-x)}{1+x^2}\textrm{d}x$ (to see this integrate by parts), which both appear in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, pages $123$-$126$ and that are evaluated by real methods exclusively.

Comment: Well, the requirements I put a month ago were in this statement: "Prove without using Euler's sum or polylogs".. But given that Ali asked another form this question today, I might edit this one so that polylogs would be fine.

Comment: @Zacky maybe less useful for you, more useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x} =
2\,\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{1 + \ic x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} + \ln^{2}\pars{1 + \ic x} -
\bracks{\vphantom{\Large A}\ln\pars{1 - x} - \ln\pars{1 + \ic x}}^{\, 2} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\underbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{I_{1}}}\ +\
\underbrace{\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + \ic x} \over x}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{I_{2}}}\ -\
\underbrace{\Re\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x \over 1 + \ic x }\,{\dd x \over x}}_{\ds{I_{3}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
I_{1} + I_{2} - I_{3}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{I_{1}\ \mbox{and}\ I_{2}}$ are trivialy evaluated with the changes
$\ds{\left.\vphantom{\large A}\pars{1 - ax} \mapsto\ x\,\right\vert_{\ a\ =\ 1,-\ic}}$ and a few *integration by parts*. Namely,
\begin{align}
I_{1} & \equiv
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{2\zeta\pars{3}}
\\[5mm]
I_{2} & \equiv
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{1 + \ic x} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[2mm] & =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\pi\,\mrm{C} + {5 \over 96}\,\pi^{2}\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 24}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} +
2\Re\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic} -
{3 \over 16}\,\zeta\pars{3}} \\ &
\end{align}

$\ds{\mrm{C}}$ is the
[Catalan Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

---

$\ds{I_{3}}$ is evaluated with the change
$\ds{\pars{1 - x}/\pars{1 + \ic x} = t}$. It's reduced to
( it's similar to the above $\mbox{cases )}$:
\begin{align}
I_{3} & \equiv \bbox[10px,#ffd]{\Re\int_{0}^{1}
\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x \over 1 - \ic x}\,{\dd x \over x}} =
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{t} \over 1 - t}\,\dd t}
^{\ds{=\ I_{1}\ =\ 2\zeta\pars{3}}}\ -\
\overbrace{\Re\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2}\pars{t} \over \ic - t}\,\dd t}
^{\ds{-\,{3 \over 16}\,\zeta\pars{3}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{{35 \over 16}\,\zeta\pars{3}}
\\ &
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x}\ln\pars{1 + x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px groove navy]{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\pi\,\mrm{C} + {5 \over 96}\,\pi^{2}\ln\pars{2} -
{1 \over 24}\,\ln^{3}\pars{2} +
2\Re\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}\,\ic} -
{3 \over 8}\,\zeta\pars{3}}
\\[5mm] &\ \approx -0.5748
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

First let's calculate the integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(y)\ln(1+y^2)}{1-y}dy$:

$$\int_0^1\frac{x\text{Li}_2(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{x}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_2(x)}{x(1+x^2)}dx$$
$$=\zeta(3)-\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\left(\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(y)}{1-xy}dy\right)dx$$
$$=\zeta(3)-\int_0^1\ln(y)\left(\int_0^1\frac{-dx}{(1+x^2)(1-yx)}\right)dy$$
$$=\zeta(3)-\int_0^1\ln(y)\left(\frac{y\ln(1-y)}{1+y^2}-\frac{\ln(2)y}{2(1+y^2)}-\frac{\pi}{4(1+y^2)}\right)dy$$
$$=\zeta(3)-\int_0^1\frac{y\ln(y)\ln(1-y)}{1+y^2}dy-\frac1{16}\ln(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{\pi}{4}G$$
$$\small{\overset{IBP}{=}\zeta(3)-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(y)\ln(1+y^2)}{1-y}dy+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-y)\ln(1+y^2)}{y}dy-\frac1{16}\ln(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{\pi}{4}G. \quad(*)}$$
On the other hand, by integration by parts we have
$$\int_0^1\frac{x\text{Li}_2(x)}{1+x^2}dx=\frac12\ln(2)\zeta(2)+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x^2)}{x}dx.\quad (**)$$
Combining $(*)$ and $(**)$ gives
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(y)\ln(1+y^2)}{1-y}dy=2\zeta(3)-\frac98\ln(2)\zeta(2)-\frac{\pi}{2}G.$$

This integral can be converted to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{H_{2n}^{(2)}}{n}$ by expanding $\ln(1+x^2)$  in series, which can be related to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{H_{2n}}{n^2}$ through the Cauchy product of $-\ln(1-x)\text{Li}_2(x)$, which is related to your integral as you showed in your question body. this way, we avoided using the generating function of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2}x^n$